# Thanks! (Gratitude Post)

Tags: discussion

I just want to say how grateful I am for everyone on this forum. I don't get around to answering others questions nearly as often as I would like to. As I continue to pursue my study of Mathematics this place has become all the more important to me. Many of the questions I have could be answered by my professors, but the faculty is sort of spread thin, and they (understandably) don't all take their work with them over the weekend.

When there's seeming ambiguity, there's someone here to clear it up.

When there's someone with difficulty realizing a pivotal step in a problem, there's someone here to point them in the right direction.

When there's a need for valuable resources to further progress understand, there's a handful of experts who seem to have read every book on the subject.

All of this is not only extremely valuable to me as a student, but also inspiring. I love this community, and I wanted to let all of you know that. Maybe this is going to be deleted. I'm not sure if this is proper [META] material, but I really wanted to give thanks. I realize that I'm doing this on Thanksgiving. I didn't realize when I started writing it, but now it is Thanksgiving post.

Happy Thanksgiving all,

Keep being awesome!

Comment: Congrats for making us remember that today is ThanksGiving Day :P .

Comment: @Anonymous: Not if you're in Canada. Or in a country other than the US.

Comment: Or if you're Wampanoag in the US.

Comment: On behalf of the site, you are welcome! If any of your classmates are facing similar issues, then they can also choose to participate in the forum, as long as they abide by the rules. Finally, even if this question is closed, your warm message is appreciated by the community.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Isn't Canada $\in \{x: x \text{ is a country }, x \neq US\}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila no.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Yes, but Canada *also* has a Thanksgiving (that I know of). So it made sense to separate it.

Comment: How I envy you having a professor to ask, at least potentially. I don't have any professors or TA to ask. All by myself. So I'm all the same grateful to those who helped me in this forum. I also would like to extend my thanks to those who despised me or can't wait to close my questions because they're too easy in their holy eyes, because they pushed me hard in making progress.

Comment: @user5280911- Very few people vote to close questions for being too easy. But we get a lot of "easy" questions that show very low effort, little research, and lack the details necessary to know how to answer. (Remember, we have almost no idea what context the questions come from.) It sounds like your progress includes learning how to better ask a questions, which is great!

Comment: @user5280911 Maybe part of it is your username, haha. I don't know, I've never been salty about a question being closed. The community seems to be really fair about that kind of thing. The one that *kind of* bothered me was my question about "interesting topologies to study", which was closed due to being subjective. I got a lot of great answers that pointed me toward topological spaces I didn't know about, links to questions that gave me motivation to study topology in general, etc. They were right though.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Sometimes I tell my own students about network, but all of my peers are graduate students. Me and all my homies *love* Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Algebraic I am sure you will continue to love it. Nobody wants to close this gratitude post of yours, so I am sure many people share the same sentiments as you. You have spoken for a lot of people, including me (and on Thanksgiving, which I don't celebrate but I am sure a lot of indebted users do), so thank you very much for this gesture, and hope to see you more on the main site!

Comment: I am glad you are enjoying the site! It is so useful for aspiring mathematicians to get and give answers. Hope you had a happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: I am the same. I kept talking about this forum to my parents, telling them how helpful people here are.

Comment: I'm amazed by the responsiveness of this community. It has helped me a lot studying maths!

Comment: @VladimirLenin Continue to follow the rules and post nice content, and we shall prosper together!